# These tags need some [static-analysis]

Tags: discussion, support, burninate-request, synonym-request, clean-up

So we've got:

- [code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-analysis) - 1220 questions

  > the process of analyzing the code of the application to discover, review, validate or verify certain properties of the application.
- [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis) - 1016 questions

  > "Static Analysis" refers to the software tools (or their use) to analyze application code for arbitrary properties, such as errors (uninitialized variables, possible SQL injection-attack, is this code-dead, can an argument be null,...) or structure (what is the call graph for this code? is there ...
- [static-code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-code-analysis) - 206 questions

  > the analysis of computer software that is performed without actually executing it.

I feel like there's a lot going on here that is more complicated than a simple synonym request.

The wiki for [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis) explicitly states it's question about tools. Tool requests are off topic, and questions about one particular tool should be tagged with the name of that tool. This suggests to me the whole tag should be burned / retagged.

[code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-analysis) and [static-code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-code-analysis) seem to be about two different things, which are **not consistently applied**

- Automatic code analysis (via a tool, IDE, or otherwise) - which relates to [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis), and possibly should be synonymed
- Manual code analysis - this could be many things, including but not limited to

  - Peer code reviews
  - Straight up debugging
  - Question like: "Why does this code work the way it does?"

These tags definitely need to be [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up), but this is more complicated than a simple "let's edit, tag and burn". With almost 2500 questions between the three tags (not counting overlap), I'm looking for people to answer with what they think should be done here. Specifically answers saying "synonym everything into [code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-analysis), then close the off-topic questions and improve the tag wiki" or "create two tags, one for manual and one for automatic", or "burn them all, tag the ones about a particular tool with that tool's tag", etc.

**I am not endorsing any particular course of action here beyond that something ought to be done.** I may make an *answer* later with a suggestion, after I've thought about it some more.

[image: Shore line cleanup]

<sub>[Image source](http://www.bp.com/en/global/corporate/gulf-of-mexico-restoration/deepwater-horizon-accident-and-response/shoreline.html)</sub>

Comment: I fully endorse that something must be done. As upvoting this is something, that's what I do until I know something better.

Comment: "questions about one particular tool should be tagged with the name of that tool." Unless it's the first question about a particular tool and the asker has less than 1,500 reputation.

Answer (score 13):

There's certainly no need for a distinction between [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis) and [static-code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-code-analysis)... this is a programming site, algorithms for static analysis of *anything* except code needs to be tagged with whatever that *anything* is.

On the other hand, Tiny Giant hints at a good point: tagging with the tool is not a good replacement for the [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis) tag, since some tool tags are very very broad ([visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) or [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) or [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc)).

Now, while some tools may be capable of both static and runtime error detection (e.g. Parasoft Insure), a questioner should know which they're asking about (or in the unusual case of both, use two tags).  For that reason, [code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-analysis) should go away as it is non-specific, and retagged with [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis) or some tag related to runtime instrumentation.  Let [static-code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-code-analysis) become a synonym for [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis), to help people who type "code-analysis" find the correct tag.

---

For the uses of "code analysis" that involve human eyes not automated tools, those belong on the sister site Software Engineering.  And the term of art is "code inspection".

Comment: To clarify, you want just one tag [tag:static-analysis], and if that tag is not appropriate, find some other more specific tag? What about creating a tag [tag:runtime-analysis]?

Comment: I second this opinion. `code-analysis` feels too broad. There should be a tag for static analysis and another for runtime analysis. These tags can then be coupled with more specific tags, such as the tools or techniques involved (metrics, coding standards, *etc*.).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you use an IDE that has lots of features. You run into an issue when using the IDE's code-analysis feature. Now you have a specific question about the issue with the code-analysis feature in relation to your code.

Your question is now about

- Your code
- The IDE
- The feature.

I believe, in this context, at least [code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-analysis) would definitely describe the content of the question, and it would help categorize the question. I suggest synonymizing [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis) and [static-code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-code-analysis) with [code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-analysis), then a clean-up of that tag.

Comment: I'm concerned we could be turning [tag:code-analysis] into a meta tag here. https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: Neither [code-analysis] nor [static-analysis] are meta tags.  They are both names for a very concrete task/feature/process.  The meaning doesn't vary either except at very fine levels of detail.  We still need some kind of tag for this concept.

Comment: Not all code analysis is static...

Comment: @BenVoigt That's why I suggested using code-analysis as the main tag. All static code analysis is code analysis, and it is the same for automatic code analysis.

Comment: @TinyGiant: There's over 1000 static code analysis questions, they don't need to be lumped into a larger category.