# Is it time for [static] to be moved?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I realized today that my next tag badge is [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static): I'll soon be an [expert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static?sort=unanswered)!

Choice morsels from the tag excerpt:

> Static is a term used in some programming languages to define a function or data storage area (field) that is not bound to any specific object instance.

> Other usage of the term static might refer to any relatively constant data. For example: in information retrieval, the output of PageRank may be referred to as the static score of a page, which will provide a boost to the dynamic score the page will get from a different algorithm.

And despite this wide tag, still the top unanswered questions are about static binaries and static libraries...

In short, the 9,000 or so questions tagged static have about nothing to do with each others; they gladly mix concepts and languages so that any hope of finding a static expert is dashed, however their sheer number is overwhelming so I do wonder what to do with this tag.

Comment: Well, if one goes with C alone, there are more distinct uses: 1. translation-unit-local globals. 2. Pointers pointing to at least n objects. 3. function-scoped objects with program lifetime. Going to C++ adds both in the first quote, but looses #2. Arguable, and it is actually argued, `static` has too many meanings in those languages alone.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes, and static libraries/binaries are yet another thing...

Comment: Though probably lower in use, I can see questions about"static" bodies in physics engines carrying the tag too.

Comment: Sorry for the hijacked title edit Matthieu, but it's not a burninate request without a terrible pun! ;) (See the related questions on the side :P)

Comment: @JamesWebster: :D

Comment: Or "Is it time for [static] to be discharged?"

Comment: @EuroMicelli: Is that a hardware joke? Poor software developer here doesn't get it... ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM. , sure, with a sprinkle of military lingo. But "Moved" is a physics joke so I feel justified. I also have an engineering one: "[static] is such a load". Too many meanings - which is also the whole point.

Comment: @EuroMicelli: To be honest, I kinda preferred your first joke to the current title, so I would not mind if you edited it.

Comment: The same could be said for [dynamic].

Comment: @FredLarson: I am not an expert in dynamic things, I would not know :D

Comment: "Shall we change the dynamics of [static]?"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Feel free to edit the title if you wish, I for one could care less about it, so have it if you think you've got better.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: :-) Oh, we don't want a dozen different titles kicking back and forth... I'm with you on Euro's "Is it time for [static] to be discharged".

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious: split the single tag [tag:static] into (on SO) [tag:static-linking] (binaries), [tag:static-variable] (storage class) and any other tags (e.g. [tag:static-web-content]?? to distinguish from dynamic web content?). @Deduplicator can you define the other common ones? **Then** change [tag:static] to a placeholder saying "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!" and listing which static- tags should be used for which purpose.

Comment: Then your responsibilities will have been fully discharged :P

Comment: Don't forget [These tags need some {static-analysis}](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300134/these-tags-need-some-static-analysis) — yet another variant of static.

Comment: @smci: I would synonymize [tag:static-variable] to [tag:global-variables] in a heartbeat. Also, tu-local globals should just be retagged to [tag:linkage]. Pointers pointing to at least n objects now... maybe a new [tag:static-pointers], though more likely [tag:pointer-to-array]. Though that's only iff we determine trying to separate it all is actually useful.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Most "static variables" are not globals, though.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, they are and they aren't. Depends on about which ones you speak, and what aspect you are focusing on.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well, application of `static` to global variables is discouraged in C++ in favor of anonymous namespaces... but static member variables (in C++) and local variables with static storage class (in both C and C++) are alive and well.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No longer discouraged. Anyway, asked on programmers why marking a symbol static (internal linkage) and putting it into an anonymous namespace isn't equivalent: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/297059/static-globals-and-anonymous-namespaces-in-c

Answer (score -10):

## Yes (Let's Get Rid of this Tag)

[We should nuke all of the tags like this, i.e. those that are way too broad to be useful to anyone.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304229/nuke-and-blacklist-all-of-the-tags-for-fundamental-programming-concepts)

Standard burnination fails the "pointless busywork" criterion of [the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) so ideally the admins would do some magic for us.

### Support from the Site Creators and Maintainers

From [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) on [the Stack Exchange Blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com), (ironically) linked to by Robert Harvey in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305739/is-it-time-for-static-to-be-moved/305793?noredirect=1#comment245994_305793) to this answer (describing what's wrong with certain overly broad tags):

> > *Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don't say anything by themselves - you can't tell what the question is about unless they're paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a problem because people don't realize this and will often use that as the question's only tag.*
>
> ### From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.
>
> How can you tell you're using a meta-tag? It's easier than you might think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves -- they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it's probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself ... is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

Yes, the above post isn't directly addressing tags like this one. [[static]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static) isn't a meta-tag but it doesn't even come close to working as the only tag on a question and the tag – as it's actually being used – "commonly means different things to different people".

### This Can Work, but it Would be a LOT Easier for the Admins

Robert Harvey comments (with some additions for clarity by me in square brackets):

> That's how tags do work on the site [like Twitter hashtags], and it's not going to get any better until we reduce the friction of making tag changes. Right now, if you want to make tag changes you have to 1. Check every question under the tag to see if it needs edits or closing, 2. Manually change the tag on each question, one at a time. Most of the time, it's not worth the effort required. It's certainly not worth the effort in this instance, since I'm not even sure there's a problem that needs fixing.

And I agree with what he wrote, somewhat. I don't think it's even worth burninating this tag! I wouldn't volunteer my time to do so. Which is why my answer to this question isn't that this should be 'burninated' but that it should be "nuked" (i.e. burninated automagically by admins or site maintainers and then blacklisted).

This tag certainly *can* be burninated, but at 9k+ questions, it will require a significant amount of effort from a good number of users. But it's certainly a lot less effort than would be required to burninate a tag like [[class]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) with 37k+ questions.

But this is *certainly* possible for the site maintainers or admins. They obviously have the ability to blacklist tags – see (or rather, don't) the [[library]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/library) tag for an example.

But if [library] is such a bad tag that the site explicitly prevents users from adding it, I submit that this tag is just as good a candidate for similar treatment.

And just to be clear – there's absolutely no reason why this tag and those that are similarly broad need to be burninated, blacklisted, or 'nuked' all at once. It's eminently and sensibly reasonable to treat each one individually. But it also seems reasonable to adopt a guideline whereby similar tags will, *eventually*, be treated in the same way.

Comment: Combine vague tags with other, more specific tags, and they suddenly become useful, e.g. [C#], [static].  You can even search for such combinations.  Alas, this point continues to be lost on most folks here.  The usual refrain is "But I can't follow tag combinations!"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Note that [C#], [static] may talk either about static variables, static method or static linking (I believe C# can be AOT). For C++ it's even worse. I think smci has the right idea and we should change all posts from [static] to more specialized tags [static-linking], [static-variable], [static-method], then it would be possible to search by tag combinations more easily... of course the right divide has to be found.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand that, because a question may involve some concept 'static', the tag indicates that fact. But so what? That's true of all the tags that were previously burninated too. Why burninate or blacklist *any* tag? They're all potentially 'useful', especially in combination with others.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: In C++ at least `static-variable` is not a useful disambiguation, because it applies to entirely different concepts depending on whether it is file-scoped, class-scoped, or local-scoped. `static-member` and `static-lifetime` (or `static-storage-class`) and `static-linkage` would be better.

Comment: @MatthieuM: Clearly not every tag is useful.  See [here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for the specific criteria that make a tag not useful.  Note that that blog post refers to tags that categorize something *other than the question's content;*  the need to pair tags doesn't necessarily mean they are bad tags, in and of itself.  Programmers tend to think in very stark, black and white terms, but that's not how most of the world works.

Comment: @BenVoigt: These are problems that can also be easily solved by combining tags.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What?  Combining tags add specificity, not ambiguity.  What do you do when you want a more specific Google Search?  You add more search terms.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "combining".  You meant "tagging with more than one", I thought you meant "merging" (and [Deduplicator is suggesting synonymization](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305739/is-it-time-for-static-to-be-moved/305793?noredirect=1#comment245875_305739))

Comment: Right; meant "pairing."

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not helpful that you're suggesting that those that disagree with you don't understand points you're making or that programmers don't understand "how most of the world works". This tag seems as low-quality as others that have been burninated or blacklisted and its not clear how your arguments are intended to be applied to them or not. The tag criteria post to which you linked also positively quotes someone arguing that problematic tags are those "that don't say anything by themselves", which seems to accurately characterize this and similar tags.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: There is a small group of people here on meta who spend a disproportionate amount of time worrying about tag hierarchies on a site that fundamentally lacks the necessary tools to make them work the way you want.  The need for extremely specific, single-subject tags is by no means a given, and Stack Exchange has consistently stayed out of the fray (with the notable exception of that blog post I linked), which means they don't consider the problem important enough to spend time on.

Comment: In other words, you're trying to build a drawbridge when we don't even have a moat.  Most tag arguments arise because people think they're a taxonomy system, when really they're more like Twitter hashtags.  If you really want better tag management, then suggest to management ways to improve the tools.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you're fighting against *any* guidelines on tags? Twitter hashtags are inherently unpolicable. That's how tags should work on this site?

Comment: That's how tags *do* work on the site, and it's not going to get any better until we reduce the friction of making tag changes. Right now, if you want to make tag changes you have to 1. Check every question under the tag to see if it needs edits or closing, 2.  Manually change the tag on each question, one at a time.  Most of the time, it's not worth the effort required.  It's certainly not worth the effort in this instance, since I'm not even sure there's a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: These are not meta-tags.  Meta-tags have to do with the presentation or author of the question, and not the technical content.  For example, `needs-editing` is a meta-tag.  [tag:static] needs some help because it is *ambiguous*, but we don't nuke ambiguous tags, we manually upgrade them to specific variants.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know – that's why I wrote in my answer "[static] isn't a meta-tag".